# turning towards an object in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Good times. How do I implement the NPC rotation towards the selected object?

```
public GameObject BufferObject;
public float MoveSpeed = 1f;
void Update()
{
    float step = MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, BufferObject.transform.position, step);
}
```

Here is the script for moving the NPC to the selected object (Buffer Object) and the movement works perfectly, but the implementation of the rotation causes Me difficulties, please advise.
For Unity2D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer and the solution from Me, albeit stupid, but working. In order to reflect the sprite, you need to get a variable, either 1 or -1 (For Scale). This code will show the distance from one NPC to the object:

```
BufferObject.transform.position.x - transform.position.x
```

And here I get a lot of values as if to the left of the NPC, then -x... , and if to the right, then x... thereby it is possible to determine which side of the object, so also level the value from here (Optional) to 1 or -1 and apply this result to transform.localScale and thereby solve the problem of how to reflect (Rotate the sprite) towards the object. Use it for your health :)
Complete code:

```
    float localPositionAmount = BufferObject.transform.position.x - transform.position.x;

    if (localPositionAmount >= 1)
    {
        gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
    }
    if (localPositionAmount <= -1)
    {
        gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
    }
    if (localPositionAmount == 0)
    {
        gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
    }
```

Yes, the code is the simplest and without enumerations and other things, but it works perfectly. I still had to figure it out myself...

Answer (score 0):

Simply get the desired direction

```
var direction = (BufferObject.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
```

and then the desired rotation using [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) like e.g.

```
var targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
```

Then either apply it directly if you want it immediately

```
transform.rotation = targetRotation;
```

Or if you want it smooth you could use e.g. [`Quaternion.RotateTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html) like

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, anglePerSecond * Time.deltatime);
```

---

Have in mind though that it might look awkward if the rotation is too slow since your NPC could move back/sidewards already while still not fully looking towards the target ;)

So you might want to wait until

```
if(Quaternion.Angle(targetRotation, transform.rotation) <= certainThreshold)
{
    ... your movement code
}
```

Comment: To put it mildly, some kind of horror is happening. The NPC is flattened and only after a long distance between the targets becomes reversible :/ Do you need screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

In a 2D space, `LookRotation` rotated around the wrong axis (around the z axis). I ended up using a calculation and assigning the angle as follows:

```
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(target.position.y - transform.position.y, target.position.x - transform.position.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
        var targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f, 0f, angle));
        transform.rotation =  Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Note the `- 90f` on the angle was just to align correctly for my sprites. The angle may be different on other oriented sprites.